# Confused by order of the Javascript AJAX example

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is probably very very easy but I'm just stuck understanding the logic. I am trying to understand how AJAX works and I found following example in w3schools.com. Examples of a few other sites are more or less the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Retrieve data from XML file</h2>

<p><b>Status:</b> <span id="A1"></span></p>
<p><b>Status text:</b> <span id="A2"></span></p>
<p><b>Response:</b> <span id="A3"></span></p>

<button onclick="loadDoc('note.xml')">Get XML data</button>

<script>
```

So, at this point, we clicked the button and function fired up.

```
function loadDoc(url) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('A1').innerHTML = xhttp.status;
      document.getElementById('A2').innerHTML = xhttp.statusText;
```

At this point, we are trying to fill the A3 span with the answer from the server. But we don't even know what is the url yet!

```
      document.getElementById('A3').innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
```

And here we have our URL,

```
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
```

We send the request

```
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Aaand credits.

```
</body>
</html>
```

To my surprise, it works without a hitch. But after setting our URL, we did not instructed the browser to update the div. We did it **before** we introduced our URL and at that point we had no data from server.

I really could not get my head around it. What is the logic of this? Does that anonymous function (the xhttp.onreadystatechange one) activated along with the xhttp.send() command? Or that onreadystatechange command loops until the conditions are met?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**From MDN onreadystatechange**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange)

> The `XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange` property contains the event handler to be called when the `readystatechange` event is fired, that is every time the `readyState` property of the `XMLHttpRequest` changes. The callback is called from the user interface thread.
>
> The `readystatechange` event will not be fired when an XMLHttpRequest request is canceled with the abort() method.

It does not keep looping, it is fired when the [readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) value is updated. The readystate has values of 0,1,2,3,4. The zero is when `open()` has not been called. Setting it before `open` is not a big deal, it does not need to be in order.

Comment: Yep, what he said :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is still a splinter in my head about this. 

So when I click the button, it first skips the anonymous function, since conditions are not met. But connection gets opened. After readystatechange reaches 4, event handler fires the anonymous function. So my next question is: Until when? Let's say there is another button with another ajax call. If I execute the second ajax call, will this fire up the first one as well, since they are following the same event handler?

Comment: No it will not fire the first one. They are separate xmlhttprequest objects.

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense. That is why it is called asynchronous isn't it ;) Thanks a lot, now I got it.

Answer (score 1):

The function doesn't run until `onreadystatechange` is called by the browser. It doesn't matter what the URL is when you define the function.

1. When the Ajax request's "ready state" changes, it runs the anonymous function.
2. The anonymous function checks to see what the request's state is.
3. If it's done, and was an HTTP OK, it updates the DOM element with the response.